# JavaFX - FXMLLoder getController() returns null

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, fxml

This is driving me nuts. I'm trying to get the controller from the FXML Loder but I get a NullPointerException.

The class where I attempt to get the controller data.

```
Node node= (Node) event.getSource();
Stage stage= (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/admin.fxml"));
BorderPane bp = loader.load();

Scene scene = new Scene(bp);

stage.setScene(scene);
adminController ac = loader.getController();
System.out.println(ac.adminName.getText());

ac.setLoggedIn(admin);


stage.show();
```

The xml file and the controller are working fine since when I remove the comment out the ac.setLoggedIn(admin) line it doesn't give me an exception.

Comment: Which reference is actually null?

Comment: @James_D the line where I try to print: ac.adminName.getText()

Comment: So, answer my question. Is `ac` null, or is `adminName` null?

Comment: @James_D I was the adminName. I fixed it. Stupid mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller I had declared the FXML object as a Label instead of text object. Also in the code I wrote here, I tried to print the admin name before I actually assigned the object to the controller.